# How should I understand 'an alarming new normal' based on given context?

Tags: meaning, context

"One particular challenge with lone wolves(terrorists who are inspired by ISIS, but not directly connected with the terrorist group) is that they are harder to detect. If there is no initial conversation between the new recruit and a known terror subject, there is no conversation to intercept, there is no meeting to observe before that terrorist is recruited and carries out an attack."

According to given context that is written above, what does the sentence below means? especially "An alarming new normal"??

*"This means a near constant state of alert -- what has been described to me repeatedly as an alarming new normal."*

I am working on translating these materials in my mother language, and for me it is hard to get the meaning of "An alarming new normal"

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Normal_(business)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An alarming standard tactic**,

or **the disturbing evolution of terrorist planning and attacks**

Answer (score 0):

It used to be that "normal" terrorism involved multiple foreign or domestic individuals whose hatred for their targets grew over time, involved extensive research, communication with others of like mind, travel and/or meetings to train in the mechanics of terrorism, and so forth; things that could conceivably be noticed and brought to light by parents or other family members, friends, the police, Homeland Security, or a variety of intelligence agencies.

Today, the "new normal" includes "lone wolf" terrorists who research and act on their own, or within a small group, without any evidence visible by others that might bring them to the attention of authorities before they could do harm. Several mass shootings and other attacks in many countries fall into this category, which has become the "new normal" for those who are charged with preventing and responding to such attacks.